# Javascript file - change source at runtime from web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="path?key=1234567890">
</script>
```

I added this in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="key" value="1234567890"/>
```

How to implement it in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` collection to access the configuration settings.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="path?key=<%=WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]%>">
</script>
```